# Datatable Colvis : enable individual column searches for columns which are initially hidden

Tags: jquery, datatable

I need to hide some columns at start and I'm doing so with the column.visible option.

The problem is that when the user uses the Colvis button to make the column reappear the column search doesn't work anymore. It seems that because the visibility extension remove the DOM element and with it the event ?

Is there a hack to make it work ?

```js
$("#table_id").append(
   $('<tfoot/>').append($("#table_id thead tr").clone())
);
var x = new Boolean("true");
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
   $('#table_id tfoot th').each(function() {
    var title = $('#table_id thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
   });
   if (x) {
    var column = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
    for (var i in column) {
     table.column(column[i]).visible(false);
    }

    var column = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    for (var i in column) {
     table.column(column[i]).visible(true);
    }
    x = !x
   };

   // Apply the filter
   $("#table_id tfoot input").on('keyup change', function() {
    table
     .column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
     .search(this.value)
     .draw();
   });


});


// DataTable
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
   colReorder: true,
   scrollX: false,

   "autoWidth": false,
   fixedHeader: true,
   "iDisplayLength": 50,
   "aLengthMenu": [
    [25, 50, 100, 200, 500, -1],
    [25, 50, 100, 200, 500, "All"]
   ],
   deferRender: false,
   'dom': 'ZBfrltip',
   buttons: ['copy', 'csv',
    {
     extend: 'colvis',
     prefixButtons: ['colvisRestore']
    }
   ],

   columnDefs: [{
    targets: '_all',
    visible: true
   }, {
    width: 200,
    targets: '_all'
   }],
});
```

Comment: Yes, the columns are removed from DOM.  And It is pretty obvious that you only will search within visible columns when you are using `.column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')` - `:visible` means exactly what you would think it means :)

Comment: can you update this https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/oMZMxd to replicate issue?

Comment: When the column is removed from DOM any event handler is also removed. Trus, you must regenerate the column footer search after a column has been made visible again; as it is now, you only create the handlers once.

Comment: So first of all I must say that I omitted the fact that I was a total noob in JS  

@davidkonrad Yes but if I make them visible again it's still not working, how could I recreate the handler when I make them reappear ?

Comment: @BhumiShah I'm sorry I can't find how to save the changes I've made but basically I've added these external sources and when you hide a column with the column visibility option you'll see that you can no longer search by column

https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution and working demo: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/bjqxzL

Changed your code to:

```
$('body').on('keyup change', '#table_id tfoot input', function() {
```

Final code:

```
$("#table_id").append(
   $('<tfoot/>').append($("#table_id thead tr").clone())
);
var x = new Boolean("true");
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
   $('#table_id tfoot th').each(function() {
       var title = $('#table_id thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
       $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
   });
   if (x) {
       var column = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
       for (var i in column) {
           table.column(column[i]).visible(false);
       }

       var column = [0, 1, 2]
       for (var i in column) {
           table.column(column[i]).visible(true);
       }
       x = !x
   };

   // Apply the filter
  $('body').on('keyup change', '#table_id tfoot input', function() {
       table
           .column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
           .search(this.value)
           .draw();
   });


});


// DataTable
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
   colReorder: true,
   scrollX: false,

   "autoWidth": false,
   fixedHeader: true,
   "iDisplayLength": 50,
   "aLengthMenu": [
       [25, 50, 100, 200, 500, -1],
       [25, 50, 100, 200, 500, "All"]
   ],
   deferRender: false,
   'dom': 'ZBfrltip',
   buttons: ['copy', 'csv',
       {
           extend: 'colvis',
           prefixButtons: ['colvisRestore']
       }
   ],

   columnDefs: [{
       targets: '_all',
       visible: true
   }, {
       width: 200,
       targets: '_all'
   }],
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much it indeed solves my problems !
You really are saving me !
Could you explain why your solution works ?
Thanks again